# Same page name and root sub-folder name conflict in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am facing a problem with wordpress url. I have a page name management and url is http://demo.com/management. But i have another subfolder in root directory name management. So when i check in the browser http://demo.com/management the page is showing blank. I am not able to rename the subfolder name.

So can anyone please help me how can i solve this? Can i redirect management subfolder to management page via htaccess. Please help

Comment: Wy don't you rename the sub folder name to something else. If that name is required then change your page slug to something else. Page name will be "Management" but change the slug to "manage" or "custom-management" something like that.

Comment: Yes if i change folder name or page slug then the issue will resolve. But for requirement i am not able to change any of those. So is there any redirect rule for htaccess in wordpress then it will be very helpful.